# XML Repository; to Save() or not to Save()

Tags: c#, .net, xml, oop, repository

What would be a better approach for an xml-based repository:

**1) Save changes to the underlying xml document on each call to the repository...**

```
public class XmlRepository1
{
    private XDocument xDocument;

    public void CrudOp()
    {
        // Perform CRUD operation...

        // Call Save()
        xDocument.Save(path);
    }
}
```

or

**2) Provide the end-user with a SaveChanges() method...**

```
public class XmlRepository2
{
    private XDocument xDocument;

    public void CrudOp()
    {
        // Perform CRUD operation...

        // DON'T call save
    }

    // Provide a SaveChanges() method to the end-user...
    public void SaveChanges()
    {
        xDocument.Save(path);
    }
}
```

My inclination leans towards option 1, because providing a SaveChanges() method doesn't really seem like a repositories responsibility. However, I'm second-guessing this decision for a couple of reasons:

a) In a multi-threaded environment, this gives the end-user an easy way to roll-back changes should a call to the repository fail, leaving objects in a partially-mutated state.

b) Option 2 provides a "batch-like" paradigm, which I can see as being more flexible for a variety of reasons.

Comment: As a comment to (a), you should never leave your repository in a partially mutated state, no matter what has happened.

Comment: @Matthew -Let me clarify... The repository won't leave objects partially-mutated. But if an end-user changes the state of an object, calls Repository.Update(obj) and the call fails... (you see where I'm going with this?) I might be over-paranoid here, I really don't know...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider adding some sort of transaction support (close to your second apporach).

```
  public class XmlRepository2 
  { 
    public void CrudOp() 
    { 
        // DON'T call save 
    } 

    public MakeTransacedChanges(Action<XmlRepository2> makeChanges)
    {
        try{ 
            makeChanges(this);
            saveChanges();
        }
        catch (RepositoryException e) 
        {
           //revert changes
        }
    }

    private void saveChanges() 
    { 
        xDocument.Save(path); 
    }
  }
```

Comment: + 1 After looking over things a few times, and considering your answer, I'm liking this idea more and more. I need to think about it a little more in the context of my program, and all of the implications... Overall, this is a good idea

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to have separate Save method in repository to have a chance to revert my changes if something will go wrong.

I found this article [Repositories and the Save Method](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2010/06/13/repositories-and-the-save-method.aspx). Hope it will help.